# How to serve non-static site from per-user website?

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, web-server

A lot of companies and universities allow members to use the `$HOME/public_html` directory as a root for their personal home pages. However, it seems the directory can only be served as a static site. Is it possible for members to serve non-static contents, e.g. to handle post requests or URL encoded parameters?

Answer (score 0):

For httpd, once the mod_userdir directive `UserDir` has been used, `Directory` can be used on the paths to alter their behavior. Including adding CGI, as mentioned in the [public_html howto](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/public_html.html#cgi):

```
<Directory "/home/*/public_html/cgi-bin/">
    Options ExecCGI
    SetHandler cgi-script
</Directory>
```

Scripts owned by any user is annoying to secure properly. An [Ubuntu wiki page on doing user dir for PHP](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UserDirectoryPHP) abandoned the suexec idea and only recommends mod_php.  I doubt php-fpm works correctly with mod_user.

Comment: With PHP-FPM every user should have an own FPM pool. This might be possible to configure on Apache, but you'd need to add the pools manually.

Comment: Is CGI the only way to achieve this?

Comment: Please be more specific in what you want to accomplish, in what language. The point is that mod_userdir maps ~user  to a directory for you. Devil is in the details of the security model of users executing code, plus which in process or CGI method you use: php-fpm, python mod_wsgi, mod_php, mod_perl, etc. etc.